# Filter a boolean column with ag-grid react/js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, filtering, ag-grid-react

I have a table (ag grid table in react), and I want to filter a boolean column (true/ false), but in ag-grid I see that there are only 3 types of filters:

1. date
2. string/ text
3. number

So boolean is treated as a text column, and this is why the filter is not working so good...

Is there a simple way to filter a boolean column? or even to create a custom filter?

thank in advanced.